# Interpreting page labels from pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm writing simple application changing page labels in pdf files. I can quite easily change (or add) page labels but I don't understand the way how they are shown by `PDFBox`. Let's take for example a [sample pdf file](https://easyupload.io/q60e1s).

`iText RUPS` shows quite easy to understand page labels:

[image]

`PDFBox PDFDebugger`, on the other hand, shows:

[image]

First page, labelled `Empty` is shown the same way in both debug application. However, When it comes to second label, `iText RUPS` shows `Cover` while `PDFBox PDFDebugger` some hard to interpret data. So, my question is: how do I interpret data given by `PDFBox` (API and debug application)?

Comment: In PDFDebugger you found the definition of the page labels of the document. In RUPS you looked at how it interprets that definition. You can also find the raw definition using RUPS by navigating to the corresponding document node. PDFDebugger on the other hand does not interpret the page label devotion. If you want to interpret the meaning of the definition, simply look at the pdf specification.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I've fixed the link.

Comment: PDFDebugger displays the page labels properly when in page view mode. What you're seeing is the raw page labels. "Cove" is a prefix. "St" 18 means the "r" after "Cove". The "r" is the numbering style "roman". Yes, it looks weird, but it's valid.

Comment: Thank you guys. Long story short, ISO 32000 for the rescue.

Comment: @mkl and Tilman Hausherr
Thanks to your comments I've written my own interpreter of page labels. Would you be so kind to do code review on appropriate SO page?

Comment: Which SO page exactly?

Comment: Why write your own interpreter when you could use the existing PDFBox code? `PDPageLabels pageLabels = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPageLabels(); String[] labels = pageLabels.getLabelsByPageIndices();`

Comment: @mkl I'd like to show my code on `https://codereview.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I want to remove some pages in PDF documents and have page labels adjusted. Interpreting page labels is a first step towards this goal.

Comment: If somebody is interested in the actual code, here it is: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286078/java-code-showing-page-labels-from-pdf-files

Comment: *"the actual code"* - @J_H already did a nice first review.